# Google Pay & Web Payment Request API:

Tags: javascript, android, google-chrome, google-pay, payment-request-api

I've been trying to implement Google Pay by following the [Google Pay API PaymentRequest Tutorial](https://developers.google.com/pay/api/web/guides/paymentrequest/tutorial). I have everything implemented, however when I try to test on my Android phone, I get the following popup:

> Request Failed
>   An unexpected error has occurred. Please try again later.

I've followed the [troubleshooting guide](https://developers.google.com/pay/api/android/support/troubleshooting), and using ADB I can see the following error:

`WalletMerchantError: Error in loadWebPaymentData: PaymentDataRequest.transactionInfo is required`

This seems to imply that `transactionInfo` should be included in my `paymentMethods` object. However, the tutorial states otherwise:

> The `transactionInfo` property should be omitted. Total price and currency should instead be specified in the `details` argument passed to PaymentRequest

Any advice?

Answer (score 2):

I recently ran into this error myself.

My own experience was that it worked with Chrome Desktop but failed on Chrome Android. I've reached out to the Google Pay team and they have acknowledge that this is a bug. No ETA on resolution for this.

The general advice is to integrate with the using the Google Pay JavaScript library instead (see: https://medium.com/dev-channel/web-payments-payment-request-api-and-google-pay-a1073e405235)

Answer (score 0):

Did you succeed with this integration? according to Google documentation it is **not recommended** to use Payment-Request-API for using Google Pay eWallet, as it said [here](https://developers.google.com/pay/api/web/guides/paymentrequest/tutorial):

> Chrome for Android is currently the only web browser supporting the
>   Payment Request API with third-party payment methods, including Google
>   Pay. Sites wishing to implement Google Pay as a standalone payment
>   method should use the Google Pay API JavaScript client library with a
>   branded Google Pay button to reach a broader Google audience across
>   multiple browsers and platforms.